Question about positive definite symmetric bilinear form on real vector space
Let $V$ be a real vector space and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ is a bilinear form which is symmetric and positive definite. More precisely,

$\langle \alpha x +\beta y. z\rangle=\alpha \langle x,z \rangle+\beta \langle y,z \rangle$ for every $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}
$ and $x,y,z\in V$.

$\langle x,y \rangle=\langle y,x \rangle$ for every $x,y\in V$.

For every $x\in V$ $\  \langle x,x \rangle\geq 0$. If $\langle x,x \rangle=0$, then $x=0$.


Notice that it is not difficult to show that the third condition is equivalent to $\forall x\in V\setminus \{0\} \ \langle  x,x\rangle>0$
Therefore, $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ is positive definite if and only if $\forall x\in V\setminus \{0\} \ \langle  x,x\rangle>0$. Hence $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ is not positive definite if and only if $\exists x\in V\setminus \{0\} \ \langle  x,x\rangle\leq 0$.
My question: Is it correct to state that symmetric bilinear form is not positive definite iff $\exists x\in V\setminus \{0\} \ \langle  x,x\rangle= 0$? The direction $\Leftarrow$ is correct but I am wondering about $\Rightarrow$.

Have you tried to formally negate condition 3 ? (of course, you first have to express it formally, using $\forall$, $\exists$, and's and or's)

take $-|x|^2$

@Exodd, I didn't get your point. What do you mean? Can you add more details please?

@FançoisGatine, yes this is what I have so far:
Positive definite (p.d.) $\Leftrightarrow (\forall x\in V \ \langle x,x\rangle\geq 0)\land (\forall x\in V \ (\langle x,x\rangle=0 \Rightarrow x=0))$. Therefore:
not p.d. $\Leftrightarrow (\exists x\in V \ \langle x,x\rangle<0)\lor (\exists x\in V \ (\langle x,x\rangle=0 \land x\neq0))$,
not p.d. $\Leftrightarrow (\exists x\in V \ \langle x,x\rangle<0)\lor (\exists x\in V\setminus {0} \ \langle x,x\rangle=0)$. I am a bit confused how to proceed

Now you want to show something of the form ($A$ OR $B$) $\implies$ $C$. You can show that this is equivalent (via some manipulations) to $(\neg A \vee C) \wedge (\neg B \vee C)$. Notice also that in your case, $B=C$, so you'll have some simplifications. This will help you have a shorter statement to prove or disprove. After that, consider Exodd's comment.

@FançoisGatine, Yes, I know that I need to prove $(A\lor B)\Rightarrow B$. So I am wondering how to prove this implication and that is my question. Can you provide more details please? Also I am not sure how to utilize Exodd's comment here.

Using the fact that $X \implies Y$ is equivalent to $\neg X \vee Y$, you can show that $(A\vee B)\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee C$, i.e. to $A \implies C$. If you translate back what this means, you will see that Exodd's comment provides a counterexample to this assertion.

@FançoisGatine, I just want to double check the logic behind the proof. We have shown that $(\text{not p.d.})\Leftrightarrow A\lor B$, where $A=(\exists x\in V \ \langle x,x\rangle<0)$ and $B=(\exists x\in V\setminus {0} \ \langle x,x\rangle=0)$. Now we want to show that $A\lor B \Rightarrow B$ but one can show that $((A\lor B) \Rightarrow B)=(A\Rightarrow B)$. Am I right that it suffices to prove that $A\Rightarrow B$?

@FançoisGatine, If yes, then I am a bit confused how to prove that $A\Rightarrow B$. If $\langle x,x\rangle<0$ for some $x\in V$, then $x\in V\setminus {0}$ but how to show that we have $B$. I am not sure how to utilize Exodd's hint.

Indeed, you have now shown that your goal is equivalent yo showing $A\implies B$. BUT you can't prove that, because it is false, Exodd gives a counterexample satisfying A but not B. So the initial implication you wanted to prove is false.

The argument I gave to try and work with the formal statement is completely unnecessary if you straight up check the counterexample. I still described it as a mean to give you some tools to advance by yourself next time you are faced with a similar statement. But maybe you already knew all those formal logic manipulations, in that case I kinda wasted your time, sorry !

@FançoisGatine, So you claim that $A \Rightarrow B$ is false because Exodd provided a counterexample. He suggested taking $-\lVert x \rVert^2$. I'm a bit confused about what he is suggesting. Does he mean to consider some specific bilinear form which satisfies $A$ but not $B$ or something else? Sorry to bother you with my questions.

@RFZ Precisely ! To make it more explicit, he suggests you consider a positive definite bilenear form <,>, and see what happens if you take the negative of that form.

@FançoisGatine, Thank you very much! It turns out that the implication I thought was correct is actually wrong. Good to know! Thanks again for the explanation!

you need to be more careful. Your  point (3)  should say that for any nonzero $x$  you have $\langle x,x \rangle  > 0$
At the end, the form fails to be positive definite if and only if there is a nonzero $x$ with $\langle x,x \rangle  \leq 0$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
There is a middle ground: if  the dimension is larger than one and  you have nonzero  independent vectors $x,y$  with  $\langle x,x \rangle  \geq  0$  and $\langle y,y \rangle  \leq  0$ then there is a nonzero vector $z,$   which is a (convex) linear combination $z = (1-t) x + t y$   such that $\langle z,z \rangle  =  0.$  Easy to find the correct $t$ value   after being told the three numbers, $\langle x,x \rangle \; , \; \; \langle y,y \rangle \; , \; \; \langle x,y \rangle \; . \; \; $
$$   \langle z,z \rangle  = (t^2 - 2t + 1)\langle x,x \rangle  + (2t-2t^2)\langle x,y \rangle  + t^2 \langle y,y \rangle $$
$$ \langle z,z \rangle  =  \left(\langle x,x \rangle -2 \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle \right) \; t^2 \; - \; 2  \left(\langle x,x \rangle - \langle x,y \rangle  \right)  t  + \langle x,x \rangle $$
Easier  with names, $A =  \langle x,x \rangle \; , \; \; $ $B =  \langle x,y \rangle \; , \; \; $ $C =  \langle y,y \rangle \; . \; \; $
$$  \langle z,z \rangle  = (A-2B + C) t^2 -2(A-B) t + A.  $$
Now we consider cases. If $(A-2B + C) = 0,$   then  $\langle x-y,x-y \rangle,$  while $x-y \neq 0$   because $x,y$ were required to be linear independent.
If $A=0$ take $t=0.$   If $C=0$  take $t=1$.
From here, we are considering $A > 0$   and $C < 0,$  with $A-2B+C \neq 0. \;$  The ordinary quadratic formula says that  we get  a $0$ inner product when
$$  t = \frac{A-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - AC}}{A-2B+C}   $$
The denominator is nonzero. As $A>0  $  and $C < 0$   we see $B^2 - AC > 0.$

I wrote condition 3 in a slightly different way but it is still equivalent to the stament you've mentioned. But I am a bit confused about the third paragraph of your answer: Is it stated under the assumption that form is positive definite or not? How do you use the fact that $\dim(V)>1$ and how to prove the existence of such independent vectors with this property? Sorry bit it is not obvious at all

I've read the addendum, and it is written very clearly! Thank you very much for that! It turns out that the existence of linearly independent $x$ and $y$ with $\langle x, x \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle y, y \rangle \leq 0$ is just a condition. One more question: I guess here you suppose that the bilinear symmetric form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is not positive definite, right? Thanks!
